# How to extract multiple bits of information that appear on different lines within the same text file

Tags: command-line, text-processing, extract

I am trying to extract the sequence ID and cluster number that occur on different lines within the same text file.

The input looks like

```
>Cluster 72
0   319aa, >O311_01007... *
>Cluster 73
0   318aa, >1494_00753... *
1   318aa, >1621_00002... at 99.69%
2   318aa, >1622_00575... at 99.37%
3   318aa, >1633_00422... at 99.37%
4   318aa, >O136_00307... at 99.69%
>Cluster 74
0   318aa, >O139_01028... *
1   318aa, >O142_00961... at 99.69%
>Cluster 75
0   318aa, >O300_00856... *
```

The desired output is the sequence ID in one column and the corresponding cluster number in the second.

```
>O311_01007  72
>1494_00753  73
>1621_00002  73
>1622_00575  73
>1633_00422  73
>O136_00307  73
>O139_01028  74
>O142_00961  74
>O300_00856  75
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Is the sequence ID always going to be the 3d space-separated field on lines that don't start with `>`? Also, you might be interested in our sister site, [bioinformatics.se].

Answer (score 13):

With awk:

```
awk -F '[. ]*' 'NF == 2 {id = $2; next} {print $3, id}' input-file
```

- we split fields on spaces or periods with `-F '[. ]*'`
- with lines of two fields, (the `>Cluster` lines), save the second field as the ID and move to the next line
- with other lines, print the third field and the saved ID

Comment: Rather than keying off the number of fields, it might be better to explicitly look for `$1 == ">Cluster"` instead of `NF == 2`, depending on what else might be in the file.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `awk` for this:

```
awk '/>Cluster/{
      c=$2;
      next
    }{
      print substr($3,2,length($3)-4), c
    }' file
```

The first block statement is capturing the cluster ID.
The second block statement (the default one) is extracting the wanted data, and print it.

Comment: You don't need to give `" "` as an argument to `print`. Just use a comma to separate the arguments and it will use the OFS, default space, to separate the arguments.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an alternative with Ruby as a one-liner :

```
ruby -ne 'case $_; when /^>Cluster (\d+)/;id = $1;when /, (>\w{4}_\w{5})\.\.\./;puts "#{$1} #{id}";end' input_file
```

or spread on multiple lines:

```
ruby -ne 'case $_
when /^>Cluster (\d+)/
  id = $1
when /, (>\w{4}_\w{5})\.\.\./
  puts "#{$1} #{id}"
end' input_file
```

I guess it's only more readable than the `awk` version if you know Ruby and regexen. As a bonus, this code might be a bit more robust than simply splitting the lines, because it looks for the surrounding text.

Answer (score 1):

Perl:

```
$ perl -ne 'if(/^>.*?(\d+)/){$n=$1;}else{ s/.*(>[^.]+).*/$1 $n/; print}' file 
>O311_01007 72
>1494_00753 73
>1621_00002 73
>1622_00575 73
>1633_00422 73
>O136_00307 73
>O139_01028 74
>O142_00961 74
>O300_00856 75
```

### Explanation

- `perl -ne`: read the input file line by line (`-n`) and apply the script given by `-e` to each line.
- `if(/^>.*?(\d+)/){$n=$1;}` : if this line starts with a `>`, find the longest stretch of numbers at the end of the line, and save that as `$n`.
- `else{ s/.*(>[^.]+).*/$1 $n/; print` : if the line doesn't start with `>`, replace everything with the longest stretch of non-`.` characters following a `>` (`>[^.]+`), i.e. the sequence name (`$1` because we have [captured](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) the regex match) and the current value of `$n`.

---

Or, for a more awk-like approach:

```
$ perl -lane 'if($#F==1){$n=$F[1]}else{$F[2]=~s/\.+$//; print "$F[2] $n"}' file 
>O311_01007 72
>1494_00753 73
>1621_00002 73
>1622_00575 73
>1633_00422 73
>O136_00307 73
>O139_01028 74
>O142_00961 74
>O300_00856 75
```

This is just a slightly more cumbersome way of doing the same basic idea as the various `awk` approaches. I am including it for the sake of completion and for the Perl fans. If you need an explanation, just use the awk solutions :).